# Conduction current for parallel-plate capacitor

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance, displacement-current

I am reading Sadiku's Elements of Electromagnetics and here is the proof given to show that conduction current = displacement current for parallel-plate capacitor.

Displacement current:
\begin{align*}
E &= \frac{V}{d}\\
D &= \epsilon E = \epsilon \frac{V}{d}\\
J_d &= \frac{\partial D}{\partial t} = \frac{\epsilon}{d}\frac{dV}{dt}\\
I_d  &= J_d \cdot S = \frac{\epsilon S}{d}\frac{dV}{dt} = C\frac{dV}{dt}\\
\end{align*}

Conduction current:
\begin{align*}
Q &=\rho_s S \\
\rho_s &= D\\
I_c &= \frac{dQ}{dt} = S \frac{d\rho_s}{dt} = S \frac{dD}{dt} = \epsilon S \frac{dE}{dt} = \frac{\epsilon S}{d}\frac{dV}{dt}
\end{align*}
the same with displacement current.

Contradictorily, it seems like this second method is also valid:
\begin{align*}
RC &= \frac{\epsilon}{\sigma}\\
R &= \frac{d}{\sigma S} \\ 
I_c &= \frac{V}{R} = \frac{\sigma S}{d} V \neq \frac{\epsilon S}{d}\frac{dV}{dt}
\end{align*}

Which method is the correct one to find conduction current then?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a series circuit consisting of a battery with emf $\mathcal E$, a capacitor $C$ and a resistor $R$.

$$\mathcal E = V_{\rm R} + \frac QC$$

Differentiating this equation with respect to time gives

$$0= \frac{dV_{\rm R}}{dt} + \frac IC$$

$$I = \frac {V_\rm R}{R} \Rightarrow 0= C\frac{dV_{\rm R}}{dt} +\frac1R V_R \Rightarrow \frac{\epsilon S}{d}\frac{dV_{\rm R}}{dt} = -\frac{\sigma S}{d} V_R$$

Comment: Quite close, but the battery is not necessarily time-invariant.

Comment: @TED The battery does not have to be there and it could be a capacitor discharging situation.

Comment: I think I see what's wrong now. The $\displaystyle R=\frac{d}{\sigma S}$ I found in my question is the resistance between capacitor plates, and $V/R$ gives the current in between the plates and not the current in the circuit loop.